# How to use BuildConfig value from the other modules?

Tags: android, gradle

I have to value in the app module BuildConfig, but I want to use this value from the other module. how can I do it?

**1-This is app Gradle:**

```
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->

        def privacyUrl = "https://www.google.com/privacy-policy"
        def termsUrl = "https://www.gogle.com/terms-of-service/"
        variant.buildConfigField "String", "URL_PRIVACY_POLICY", "\"${privacyUrl}\""
        variant.buildConfigField "String", "URL_TERMS_OF_USE", "\"${termsUrl}\""

        if (variant.name.startsWith("development")) {

            def domain = "https://api.dev.google.com/"
            def countryCode = "+63"
            variant.buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"${domain}\""
            variant.buildConfigField "String", "COUNTRY_CODE", "\"${countryCode}\""
        } else if (variant.name.startsWith("staging")) {

            def domain = "https://api.stage.google.com/"
            def countryCode = "+0000"

            variant.buildConfigField "String", "COUNTRY_CODE", "\"${countryCode}\""
            variant.buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"${domain}\""

        }

        //production
        else {

            def domain = "https://api.google.com/"
            def countryCode = "+000"

            variant.buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"${domain}\""
            variant.buildConfigField "String", "COUNTRY_CODE", "\"${countryCode}\""
        }
    }
```

**2-This is profile module gradle:**

```
android {
    compileSdk Versions.compile_sdk_version

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk Versions.min_sdk_version
        targetSdk Versions.target_sdk_version
        versionCode Versions.version_code
        versionName Versions.version_name

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    enableCompose(this)
}
```

I want to use privacyUrl and termsUrl in the profile module but I don't have access to the app module BuldConfig

Comment: This is not possible is guess. You can't use apps buildConfig  values in other modules , this is only accessible inside the app only, but other modules build config values can be used in app

Comment: @MriDx So how can I set the value to profile module and read data's

Comment: You can't, pass build config values to profile module from app module. Lets say you have a profile activity in profile module, and you need api key from build config of app module in profile activity, and you're starting profile activity from home activity, then before starting profile activity retrieve build config value, api key in this case and pass in bundle to profile activity.

Comment: @MriDx I fixed it, I added URLs to the profile module's build.gradle.                                 this lines:                                                                                                                                    `def privacyUrl = "https://www.google.com/privacy-policy"
        def termsUrl = "https://www.gogle.com/terms-of-service/"
        variant.buildConfigField "String", "URL_PRIVACY_POLICY", "\"${privacyUrl}\""
        variant.buildConfigField "String", "URL_TERMS_OF_USE", "\"${termsUrl}\""`